# XML Schema Validations fails - invalid content was found starting element

Tags: xml, validation

created my own XML document with attributes, tags and etc. According to this XML document, I want to create an XML Schema, but Validator always failing with error:

> Cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'wh:warehouses'. One Of '{warehouses}' Is Expected., Line '2', Column '64'.

I can't find the bug in my XML Schema. Where is the problem? I tried almost everything to fix. Googled everything, read all Stackoverflow topics, but no idea came to my head.

XML: [My XML](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-editor/494634)

XML Schema: [My XML Schema](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-editor/38bae0)

Comment: Where in the schema do you define the namespace?

Comment: Please post minimal schema and instance as part of the question; we don't want to go following links,